# How to best read large dataset from disk

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, dataset

I want to solve a task using a ResNet in keras and tensorflow. My Dataset is big, and right now I'm considering my data loading options and trying to determine which one suits the task best.

About the **Dataset**:

- x: arrays of 200x700 cells in range -1.0...1.0, I don't want to downsample them; they are currently saved as matlab or npz file
- y: the label consists of two floats per x.
  I have 1.2Million of these (x, y) which are currently saved in 1000 npz files, each with 1GB, totalling to 1TB of data.

**Problem**: I don't have 1TB RAM in my system, so I can't keep all the data in memory. Thus I need a suitable solution to read my data from disk while training my neural network.

**Solutions** that I found so far:

- save these files as images and use keras dataset io ["load_images_from_directory"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory), downside: I need to save the images on disk which would probably take even more than 1TB. And what about the labels? Plus probably additional preprocessing to from range 0..1 to -1..1
- [tfrecords](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datahttps://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) which feels like an overkill, since my dataset is not really a structured one but it's just (array, label)
- [hdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097970/tensorflow-io-dataset-input-pipeline-with-very-large-hdf5-files) which is also more for structured/hierarchical data.

Things that I also want to **take into account:**

- Do I save my data as is, or do I need to save shuffled batches? But according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/why-should-we-shuffle-data-while-training-a-neural-network/311318#311318) I should also shuffle the mini-batches in each epoch new. This would mean that the order and filesizes (e.g. one file is one mini-batch) whith which I save my files is not important - the mini-batches should be shuffled anyways.
- Later, I will most likely also need to transfer the whole project to pytorch, so a data storage which is supported by both (kears/tensorflow and pytorch) can save me some time later.
- If I store each (x,y) sample as one small .bin file, this file is smaller than the block size of my disk, thus using more disk size than necessary.

So the **question** is: What are the pros and cons specific to my dataset/task, thus which dataloading should I use? Are there more options that I haven't discovered yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way is to create a class inheriting `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`. This class implements a function `__getitem__` which is called when you use [`model.fit()` method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). In this method, you can simply load one batch at a time, so no need to load the whole dataset. [See the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence). You can also directly use the `.npz` files when calling `__getitem__`.

## Shuffle data

> Do I save my data as is, or do I need to save shuffled batches?

You would implement the method `on_epoch_end()` that does the shuffling of a list of `indices`. Then when you load a `.npz` file, use something like `data[indices[i]]` which load the index `i` in the shuffled list of indices.
`on_epoch_end` is called at the end of each epoch by `.fit()` method, and you can also use it in `__init__` of your `Sequence` class to initialize the shuffle.

## From Keras to Pytorch

Pytorch has similar module called `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. The conversion is straightforward. [See this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).